# Ubuntu 14.04: VMWare fusion 6.0.3 Share is getting removed after newest update and reboot

Tags: 14.04, updates, samba, vmware-fusion

I have a mac book pro, and run VMWare fusion 6 on it to run ubuntu at the same time as OSx.  When I first attemped to do this, I couldn't get the share to work after initial sudo apt-get update for versions 12.04, 13.10 and 14.04a. None of them would allow me to share. Finally, one day I saw 14.04 officially released, I downloaded it and tried it, and POOF, the share worked after install as well as after update!

So there is something in this newest update that is messing up and removing my shared folder so that I can access my OSx file directory. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Maybe something to do with 'samba'? Is there an update for that?